# Issue with AutoSizeText in Row

Tags: flutter, dart

**ISSUE:**

I have problem with my flutter code. In code, I have `AutoSizeText` (library from pub.dev), and when I'm using `AutoSizeText` like this, it doesn't work. (Font size doesn't change if I have long text and text will overflow out of padding.)
Do someone have idea what's wrong?

**CODE:**

```
                    Row(children: <Widget>[
                       FutureBuilder(
                           future: returnName('CV_A_theNumberOfWordsIKnow'),
                           builder: (context, snapshot) {
                             return AutoSizeText(snapshot.data + ":",
                                 style: TextStyle(
                                   color: Colors.white,
                                 ),
                                 minFontSize: 1,
                                 maxLines: 1,
                           );
                           }),
                       Text(" "),
                       Text("0/50",
                           style: TextStyle(
                               color: Colors.white,
                               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                     ]),
                   ],
                 ),
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap `AutoSizeText` into `Expanded` widget.